# How to animate between two layout states in Jetpack compose, similar to how MotionLayout animates constraints?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, android-motionlayout

Using `MotionLayout` we can animate view constraints, such as views can be re-arranged while animating between the different "arrangements"

How can we achieve the same using `Composables` in jetpack compose?

I've written a quick example to help demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

Let's say we have an `Image` with a `Text` underneath, and when a button is clicked, we want to alter the layout in a way where the text becomes aligned to the right of the image.
That's pretty simple using `MotionLayout`, we just define 2 layout states describing the above, with transition between them.

I can't find anything similar in compose.
The code below for example will simply re-compose the view and "snap" between the 2 states rather than animate.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun MainLayout(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
  var isVertical by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
  Box(
    modifier = Modifier
      .fillMaxSize()
      .background(color = Color.Black)
  ) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
      Button(
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
        onClick = { isVertical = !isVertical }) {
        Text(text = "toggle")
      }
      if (isVertical) {
        VerticalState()
      } else {
        HorizontalState()
      }
    }
  }
}

//@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun VerticalState(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
  Column(
    modifier = Modifier
      .padding(top = 100.dp)
      .fillMaxWidth()
  ) {
    Image(
      modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
      painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
      contentDescription = "image"
    )
    Text(
      modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
      text = "Some text",
      color = Color.White
    )
  }
}

//@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun HorizontalState(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
  Row {
    Image(
      painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
      contentDescription = "image"
    )

    Text(
      modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
      text = "Some text",
      color = Color.White
    )
  }
}
```

How can I animate between VerticalState and HorizontalState? Or how do I achieve the desired effect?